# OpenGL crashes at glTexImage2D(...)

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, jpeg, libjpeg

I wrote an image viewer in OpenGL (+GLEW and GLFW) to learn how to handle textures etc. but the program keeps crashing when I feed it certain jpeg files (most of them work). I tried using SOIL, libjpeg and jpgd, but it crashes anyway so it's not the decompressor's fault.

I checked (using output_* jpg decompressor variables) the file data after decompressing it (height, width, channels) and they are correct. I also dumped both of them to .raw file and opened them in Photoshop and they load without any problems (though I had to enter number of channels, dimensions and check interleaved). It's not a problem with the size because 3000x2800 jpg loads normally and 667x1111 crashes OpenGL. Comparing color hex values and file loaded in hex editor gave the same result in both cases - it's a pure RGB 8 bits per channel image data.

Here's my jpeg decompressin code (byte is just an unsigned int):

```
inline bool loadTexture(byte *&texture, const char *fName, int &width, int &height, int &actualComp, int reqComp)
{
    texture = decompressJpeg(fName, width, height, actualComp, reqComp);
    if(texture == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout<<"SOIL decoded\n";
        texture = SOIL_load_image(fName, &width, &height, &actualComp, reqComp);
        if(texture == nullptr)
            return GL_FALSE;
    }
    return GL_TRUE;
}

unsigned char* decompressJpeg(const char *fName, int &width, int &height, int &actualComp, int reqComp)
{
    std::ifstream f(fName, std::ios::binary);
    if(!f.is_open())
        return nullptr;
    struct jpeg_decompress_struct cinfo;
    struct jpeg_error_mgr errManager;
    cinfo.err = jpeg_std_error(&errManager);
    jpeg_create_decompress(&cinfo);

    f.seekg(0, f.end);
    size_t length(f.tellg());
    f.seekg(0, f.beg);
    byte *data(new byte[length]);
    f.read((char*)data, length);
    f.close();

    jpeg_mem_src(&cinfo, data, length);
    jpeg_read_header(&cinfo, TRUE);
    cinfo.out_color_space = JCS_RGB;

    jpeg_start_decompress(&cinfo);

    height = cinfo.output_height;
    width = cinfo.output_width;
    actualComp = cinfo.output_components;
    unsigned char **tempVal(new unsigned char*[cinfo.output_height]);
    for(int i(cinfo.output_height); i>0; --i)
    {
        *tempVal = new unsigned char[cinfo.output_width*cinfo.output_components];
        ++tempVal;
    }
    tempVal -= cinfo.output_height;

    while(cinfo.output_height > cinfo.output_scanline)
    {
        jpeg_read_scanlines(&cinfo, tempVal, 1);
        ++tempVal;
    }
    tempVal -= cinfo.output_height;

    jpeg_finish_decompress(&cinfo);
    delete[] data;

    unsigned char *retVal(new unsigned char[actualComp*height*width]);
    for(int i(height); i>0; --i)
    {
        for(int j(width*actualComp); j>0; --j)
        {
            *retVal = **tempVal;
            ++retVal;
            ++(*tempVal);
        }
        (*tempVal) -= width*actualComp;
        delete[] *tempVal;
        ++tempVal;
    }
    tempVal -= height;
    delete[] tempVal;
    jpeg_destroy_decompress(&cinfo);
    retVal -= height*width*actualComp;
    return retVal;
}
```

And here's the rest of the code:

```
#include <glew.h>
#include <glfw3.h>
#include <SOIL.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <conio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <jpeglib.h>

#define HEIGHT  1024
#define WIDTH   1280

typedef unsigned char byte;

void key_callback(GLFWwindow *window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode);
inline void writeErrLog(const GLchar *log);
inline const bool loadShader(const GLuint shader, const char *sourceFile);
inline bool loadTexture(byte *&texture ,const char *fName, int &width, int &height, int &actualComp, int reqComp);
unsigned char* decompressJpeg(const char *fName, int &width, int &height, int &actualComp, int reqComp);

struct bitmap
{
public:
    bitmap() : width(0), height(0), data(nullptr) {}
    int width, height;
    byte *data;
};

std::string programPath;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if(argc<2)
        return -1;

    programPath = *argv;
    programPath.erase(programPath.rfind('\\')+1);

    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);
    GLFWwindow *window(glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Okienko", nullptr, nullptr) );
    if(window == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout<<"Failed to create window\n\n";
        glfwTerminate();
        getch();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    if(glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
    {
        std::cout<<"Failed to initialize GLEW\n\n";
        glfwTerminate();
        getch();
        return -1;
    }
    glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    unsigned long long int frame_time(0);

    const GLuint    vertexShader(glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER)),
            fragmentShader(glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)),
            shaderProgram(glCreateProgram());
    GLint   operationStatus;

    std::string shaderPath(programPath);
    shaderPath.append("shaders\\vertex shader.glsl");
    if(loadShader(vertexShader, shaderPath.c_str()) == GL_FALSE)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        getch();
        return -1;
    }
    shaderPath = programPath;
    shaderPath.append("shaders\\fragment shader.glsl");
    if(loadShader(fragmentShader, shaderPath.c_str()) == GL_FALSE)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        getch();
        return -1;
    }
    shaderPath.clear();

    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
    glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &operationStatus);
    if(operationStatus == 0)
    {
        GLchar log[2048];
        glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, 2048, nullptr, log);
        glfwTerminate();
        writeErrLog(log);
        return -1;
    }
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);

    bitmap texture;
    int comp;
    if(loadTexture(texture.data, *(argv+1), texture.width, texture.height, comp, 3) == GL_FALSE)
    {
        std::string errLog("Failed to read texture. (");
        errLog.append(*(argv+1));
        errLog.append(")");
        writeErrLog(errLog.c_str());
        errLog.clear();
    }
    std::cout<<"channels:\t"<<comp<<'\n';

    std::ofstream nam("image.raw", std::ios::binary);
    nam.write((char*)texture.data, texture.width*texture.height*comp);
    nam.close();

    //GLint inColorUni(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "inColor"));
    int newWidth, newHeight;
    if( (float(texture.width)/float(texture.height)) / (float(WIDTH)/float(HEIGHT)) > 1.0f)
    {
        newWidth = std::min(texture.width, WIDTH);
        newHeight = round(float(newWidth) / (float(texture.width)/float(texture.height)));
    }
    else
    {
        newHeight = std::min(texture.height, HEIGHT);
        newWidth = round(float(newHeight) *     (float(texture.width)/float(texture.height)));
    }
    // normalize
    GLfloat x(GLfloat(newWidth)/GLfloat(WIDTH)*2.0f),
            y(GLfloat(newHeight)/GLfloat(HEIGHT)*2.0f);

    GLsizei vertices_len(20);
    GLfloat *vertices(new GLfloat[vertices_len]);
    GLfloat diffX((2.0f-x)/2.0f), diffY((2.0f-y)/2.0f);

    std::cout   <<"Resolution:\t"<<texture.width<<'x'<<texture.height<<"px"
                <<"\nScaled:\t"<<newWidth<<'x'<<newHeight<<"px"
                <<"\nNormalized:\t";

    *vertices = -1.0f+diffX;        //X
    *++vertices = 1.0f-diffY;       //Y
    *++vertices = 0.0f;     //Z
    *++vertices = 0.0f;     //S
    *++vertices = 1.0f;     //T

    *++vertices = -1.0f+diffX;  //X
    *++vertices = -1.0f+diffY;  //Y
    *++vertices = 0.0f;     //Z
    *++vertices = 0.0f;     //S
    *++vertices = 0.0f;     //T

    *++vertices = 1.0f-diffX;       //X
    *++vertices = -1.0f+diffY;  //Y
    *++vertices = 0.0f;     //Z
    *++vertices = 1.0f;     //S
    *++vertices = 0.0f;     //T

    *++vertices = 1.0f-diffX;       //X
    *++vertices = 1.0f-diffY;       //Y
    *++vertices = 0.0f;     //Z
    *++vertices = 1.0f;     //S
    *++vertices = 1.0f;     //T
    vertices -= vertices_len-1;

    GLsizei indices_len(6);
    GLuint *indices(new GLuint[indices_len]);
    *indices = 0;
    *++indices = 1;
    *++indices = 3;
    *++indices = 1;
    *++indices = 2;
    *++indices = 3;
    indices -= 5;

    GLsizei color_len(4);
    GLfloat *color(new GLfloat[color_len]);
    *color = 0.5f;
    *++color = 0.0f;
    *++color = 1.0f;
    *++color = 1.0f;
    color -= 3;

    GLuint triangleVBO, triangleObjectVAO, triangleEBO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &triangleObjectVAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &triangleVBO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &triangleEBO);

    glBindVertexArray(triangleObjectVAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleVBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat)*vertices_len, vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleEBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLuint)*indices_len, indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5*sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5*sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(3*sizeof(GLfloat)) );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    glBindVertexArray(0);

    delete[] vertices;
    delete[] indices;

    #define OKRES 7000.0
    GLfloat timePoint(0.0f);

    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

    GLuint tex;
    glGenTextures(1, &tex);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, texture.width, texture.height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture.data);
        GLfloat bgColor[] = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameterfv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BORDER_COLOR, bgColor);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    //SOIL_free_image_data(texture.data);

    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glfwPollEvents();

        if(clock()-frame_time > 16) /* max 60 fps */
        {
            glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            /*timePoint += clock()-frame_time;
            if(timePoint>OKRES)
                timePoint -= OKRES;
            glUniform4f(inColorUni, 0.0f, 0.0f, sinf(3.1415926f * (timePoint/OKRES)), 1.0f);*/

            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
            glBindVertexArray(triangleObjectVAO);

            //glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

            glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
            glBindVertexArray(0);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

            glfwSwapBuffers(window);
            frame_time = clock();
        }
    }

    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &triangleObjectVAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &triangleEBO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &triangleVBO);
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Don't tell me how to optimize my code (except it's about handling an jpg, as it's just a kind of tutorial project. I didn't care about optimizations and stuff. I just want my jpeg to load and not crash the OpenGL.

It crashes at

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, texture.width, texture.height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture.data);
```

I think that shaders, key callback, loadShaders and writeErrLog are irrelevant since they are as basic as they can be (vertex shader actually does nothing, and fragment shader only uses texture() ) but I'll post them if needed. Also don't ask me why I assign vertices that way.

Both of the tested jpegs don't seem to be progressive.
It seems that I gave glTexImage2D() incorrect values. Could endianness cause it or something? (I don't know much about how to write endianness-safe code) Also, how does OGL determine if the given array is bad (other than size != channels x height x width)?

Comment: You seem really concerned about whether your code is optimized.  Don't worry about optimization.

Comment: My main concern with the code is how convoluted the JPEG reading function is.  You don't need to allocate a separate piece of memory for each scanline.  Also, the fact that the function does a bunch of pointer arithmetic and then "undoes" the pointer arithmetic to get back to the start of the buffer is a bit disturbing (talking about `retVal -= height*width*actualComp;`).  These things make it hard to tell if the code is correct or not, if it were simpler, it might be more obvious that the code is correct or incorrect, and where the error is.

Comment: Thanks. I just changed the decompressJpeg() function, as the ptr to ptr was really slowing things down. It made me allocate twice as much memory (and slowed down the process by copying the data again after the decompression process). The code was correct btw (The program worked after changing how OpenGL reads pixel data), but the truth is I have tendency to overcomplicate my code, or make it human-unreadeable just to make it compact.